# how to pass date datatype in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
[HttpPost] 
public JsonResult GetSearchedResults(string searchedHotel)  
{    
  var searchingHotels = clsRepository.GetSearchedResults(searchedHotel, );
  return json etc etc
}
```

This is my Controller. Just Like String, I need to pass Date Datatype. I have A field Name in DataBase of Type Date.Now I need to pass this.how to pass a datatype DATE.?

> I have a DatePicker is my main page. When i choose A date from Datepicker, that will be saved in a variable in my Jquery file. so I need to pass this variable to controller.i need to check whether selected date and date in DataBase are equal.

Comment: What do you want to pass from where to where? From the view to the controller? Just change your action parameter to datatype DateTime

Comment: I have a DatePicker is my main page. When i choose A date from Datepicker, that will be saved in a variable in my Jquery file. so I need to pass this variable to controller.i need to check whether selected date and date in DataBase are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the datatype of your action parameter to `DateTime`. The default modelbinder will try to convert the value of the sent request parameter to a `DateTime` value.

```
public JsonResult GetSearchedResults(DateTime myDateParameter)  
{    
    // do whatever you want with your date

}
```

Comment: first time when i  tried to type DateTime, DateTime was not shown in Intellisense. Anyway Thanx :)

Comment: @gou The `DateTime` type is contained in the `System` namespace. So maybe you hadn't included that namespace

Answer (score 0):

Make an ajax POST request to your action with the date as a parameter.
Use jQuery to make the request. See the dosc on how you can do it: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/